# LIbGdx - Google play Services - Error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, google-play

I am pretty new to LibGDX and I don't have much experience.
I am trying to get Google play services to my project, however, I'v encountered an error in Android Studio

> H:\JimmyCode\ActiveProjects\test\test4\test4\core\src\com\fish\test\SI.java
>
> Error:(8, 25) error: cannot find symbol class ActionResolver
>
> Error:(14, 16) error: cannot find symbol class ActionResolver
>
> Error:(11, 30) error: cannot find symbol class ActionResolver

I followed the tutorial [Here](http://theinvader360.blogspot.ca/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html)
but I set up the libraries according to [this way](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX).
I used the inteliJ idea setup method for including BaseGameUtils.

Next I finished my android Manifest and Android Launcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fish.test1.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.fish.test.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Then on the Android Launcher

```
package com.fish.test.android;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.fish.test.SI;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener, ActionResolver {
private GameHelper gameHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    initialize(new SI(this), config);

    if (gameHelper == null) {
        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
        gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    }
    gameHelper.setup(this);

}


@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
}
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
}

@Override
public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
    return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
}

@Override
public void loginGPGS() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
    }
}

@Override
public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "CgkIuJC4198fEAIQAA", score);
}

@Override
public void submitStarGPGS(int score) {
    Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "CgkIuJC4198fEAIQAQ", score);
}

@Override
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "CgkIuJC4198fEAIQAA"), 100);
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "CgkIuJC4198fEAIQAQ"), 100);
    }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
    }
}

@Override
public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
    Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);
}

@Override
public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
        }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
        }
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {

}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {

}
}
```

And finally on the LibGdx Class

```
package com.fish.test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.fish.test.AssetLoaders.MainLoader;
import com.fish.test.Screens.SplashScreen;

public class SI extends Game{
public static ActionResolver actionResolver;

static {
    actionResolver = new ActionResolver();
}

public SI (ActionResolver actionResolver)
{
    this.actionResolver = actionResolver;
}

@Override
public void create () {
    // load all texture :P
    MainLoader.load();
    // setScreen to GameScreen
    this.setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void render () {
    // important!!! needed for the rendering of other screens ;)
    super.render();
}

@Override
public void dispose()
{
    // dispose the, now, unneeded assets
    MainLoader.dispose();
}



}
```

Comment: Did you put your ActionResolver interface file in your **core** module or your **android** module? It needs to be in core.

Comment: No i didn't,  thank you for helping. I tried it, I worked